# Basic Javascript, How can i filter an array by numeric value?

Tags: javascript

this is my first question on this community and i'm a novice programmer with JavaScript.

I have something like this:

```
let dog = [["extra small", 2], ["small", 5], ["medium", 7], ["big", 9], ["extra big", 12]];
```

Taking the data of the previous array, i want to create a new array just with the numeric values, for example:

```
ages = [2, 5, 7, 9, 12]
```

I tried to use "filter", but i don't know how to properly use it, also i tried to search some references to make it work but i couldn't.

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my poor english, but i suppose you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

You can first use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get just the numbers and then [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the numbers

```js
let dog = [
  ["extra small", 2],
  ["small", 5],
  ["medium", 7],
  ["big", 9],
  ["extra big", 12]
];

let ages = dog.map(([size, age]) => age).sort((a, b) => a - b);

console.log(ages);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dog = [
  ["extra small", 2],
  ["small", 5],
  ["medium", 7],
  ["big", 9],
  ["extra big", 12]
];

const newArr = dog.map(item => {
  return item[1]
})

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here are my thoughts on how to achieve this.
>
> 1. Using [Array#Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
>    Basically, mapping each element of the array, then checking for the numeric values in the subArray using [JavaScript#isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and
>    returning the numbers.
>
>    - isNaN() checks if the value type is not a number. !isNaN() reverses that response.
>    - [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is used to flatten the final result to a single array. Alternatively, you can change map() to [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
 // map(), isNaN(), filter(), flat()
 let newArr = dog.map((arr) => arr.filter((val) => !isNaN(val))).flat();
 console.log(newArr); // [ 2, 5, 7, 9, 12 ]


 // flatMap(), isNaN(), filter()
 let newArr = dog.flatMap((arr) => arr.filter((val) => !isNaN(val)));
 console.log(newArr); // [ 2, 5, 7, 9, 12 ]
```

> 2. Using function.
>    This is similar to the first, however, instead of using map() we use a [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the array.

```
function getNumeric(array) {
    let result = [];
    array.forEach((arr) => {
        let res = arr.filter((a) => !isNaN(a));
        result.push(...(res));
    });
    return result;
}
let newArr = getNumeric(dog);
console.log(newArr); // [ 2, 5, 7, 9, 12 ]
```